# How to know whether visualforce page is being used by community or internally

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

i have a visualforce page in my org.this visualforce page can be accessed internally in org by /apex/sample as well as in a community.there is slight difference in behaviour.How to know whether it is accessed in community or internally using visualforce or apex.Please guideline.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [UserInfo class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) to query either the user's profile or license type, and change behavior based on that. If the behavior difference is related to showing/hiding fields or making some read-only, you can also achieve that natively through FLS.

Comment: Hi, getting this error for it now, seems doc. no longer available in link: Sorry, the document you are looking for doesn't exist or could not be retrieved.

Comment: Updated with working URL. :)

Comment: I believe either query for networkid or contact may be eaiser to manage